# Create a view with user selected fields

Tags: views, entities, importing-exporting

I need to create a view with user selected fields. My basic requirement is *data export*. My site contains around 1500 nodes and each node has around 25 fields. I have a view for *data export* with 5 fields.

My specific need is to create a control panel for selecting the fields i want – and in a following step I have to create a view with the selected fields.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as you need [Views Dynamic Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dynamic_fields). From the project page:

> The Views Dynamic Fields module provides a filter for use with Views module. This filter allows the user to pick and choose which fields to display for a rendered instance of a view for that user. This provides a customized view instance for each user.
>
> This module provides additional advantages when used with the Views Bonus Pack module or the Views Excel Export module to generate an xls file from a view. The xls file will only display the fields you have chosen on the rendered view instance in browser.